AM-GM inequality for non necessary positive numbers
For nonnegative real numbers $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ ($n\geqslant2$), it is well known that :
$$n\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^n\tag{$\star$}$$since this is equivalent to the AM-GM inequality.
But for $n=2$, it happens that we have $2x_1x_2\leqslant x_1^2+x_2^2$ for any pair $(x_1,x_2)$ of real numbers.
And for $n=3$, one can see that :
$$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^2-3x_1x_2x_3=(x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-x_1x_2-x_1x_3-x_2x_3)$$hence, under the assumption $x_1+x_2+x_3\geqslant 0$, we have :$$3x_1x_2x_3\leqslant x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3$$
since $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-x_1x_2-x_1x_3-x_2x_3=\frac12\left((x_1-x_2)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2+(x_3-x_1)^2\right)\geqslant0$$
Now my question is the following :
Given an integer $n\geqslant2$, under what condition do we have $(\star)$ ?
EDIT :
After a few comments, I guess I have to reformulate the question in a more precise way ...
The strong form of the question would be to describe the set $E_n$ of all $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $(\star)$ is true. It appears that $E_2=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $E_3\supset\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3;\,x_1+x_2+x_3\geqslant0\}$. From the AM-GM inequality, we know that $E_n\supset[0,+\infty)^n$ for all $n\geqslant2$.
The weak form of it would be to find a sufficient condition for the condition $(\star)$ to be true.

$$n\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^n$$ is not AM-GM. That would be $$n^n\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\leqslant\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^n$$

@Arthur But if, in your AM-GM inequality, you replace $x_i$ with ${x_i}^n$ and then take $n-$th roots of both sides, you do get OP's inequality. So actually, OP is right.

OP - please can you clarify the question, " Given an integer $n\geqslant2$, under what condition do we have $(\star)$ ?, " with more context as to what you're actually asking. Thanks. To me, this question is ambiguous and can be interpreted in different ways.

@AdamRubinson I have edited and tried to clarify my question.

Your observatiopn for $n=2$ generalizes to even $n$: If $n$ is even, then your left hand side is  $\le n\prod|x_i|$, which by AM-GM is $\le \sum|x_i|^n=\sum x_i ^n$.

@HagenvonEitzen Yes, the remaining question is all about the odd case.

If I could prove that, when $n$ is odd, $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\geqslant0$ implies $(\star)$, it would solve the whole problem because assuming that $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\leqslant0$ would give $n\prod_{i=1}^n{(-x_i)}\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^n(-x_i)^n$, and so $n\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}\geqslant\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^n$.

After some numerical experimentations, I see that the above conjecture is false. For example, if we choose $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(-2,1,1,1,0)$, we get $\sum_{i=1}^5x_i^5-\prod_{i=1}^5x_i=-29<0$

@Adren For example, if $4^{4/5}\sum_{i=1}^5 \min(0, x_i)

\sum_{i=1}^5 \max(0, x_i) \ge 0$, then
$x_1^5 + x_2^5 + x_3^5 + x_4^5 + x_5^5 - 5x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5 \ge 0$.

